# Regex MySQL find words separated by punctuation

Tags: regex

Take an input like `"This is, in text, an example! Cool stuff"`

I have some C# code that takes it, removes the punctuation, splits on the spaces, and returns the first 6 elements:

```cs
 var title = new string(input.Where(c => !char.IsPunctuation(c)).ToArray()).Split(' ').Take(6);
```

so I get an array of:

`["This", "is", "in", "text", "an", "example"]`

From that array, how can I work backwards to match it to the original input? I've tried doing:
`'This|is|in|text|an|example'` but it's not precise enough, as I think it's going or's instead of and's.

I'm going to use the regex expression in an SQL query, something like:

```sql
SELECT t.*, Max(e.Timestamp) As EventUpdated, Min(e.Timestamp) as Timestamp
        From test t
        Left Join edithistory e on t.IdTimelineinfo = e.IdTimelineinfo
        where t.date = "2020-12-06" and t.Title REGEXP 'Testing|two|events|on|the';
```

I'm really new to regex and would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal or end result that you want here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated my question, the end goal if for it to be used in an SQL query.

Comment: If you're on MySQL, then I recommend reading about full text search before you continue down this path.

Comment: I just looked into full text search and It appears that it has a list of stopwords that it doesn't index on, and when I try to include them like ```'Testing+two+events+on+the'``` in a boolean mode full text search, I'm returned nothing. But when I try to do ```'Testing+two+event'``` it works ofc. I looked into it and it appears that I would have to remove the entire stopword list to get around this issue. I think it would probably be easier to just use Regex instead.

Comment: ...or maybe not.  I'd rather modify the stopwords list.  In any case, full text search might be using regex itself under the hood.

Comment: hmm, I could also just remove all the words in my array that are in the stopword list before I pass it to the sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using REGEX like the following:

```cs
  DbTitle = string.Join("[^a-zA-Z]*", ArraryOfWords);
  var title = $"[^a-zA-Z]*{DbTitle}";
```

```sql
SELECT t.*, Max(e.Timestamp) As EventUpdated, Min(e.Timestamp) as Timestamp
         From test t
         Left Join edithistory e on t.IdTimelineinfo = e.IdTimelineinfo
         where t.date = @date and t.Title Regexp @title and Confirmed = 1;
```